# How to announce the status of a toggle after being pressed in Assistive Technology?

Tags: html, accessibility

By assistive technology I am referring to using a screen reader like NVDA.

If I use aria's role property, I can have it announce "Mute button toggle on" but this doesn't read anything when the user presses enter or space to change whether it's muted or unmuted. I'd like to either say something like "Now unmuted" or just re-read the state of the toggle when the user changes it.

Relevant HTML:

```
<button tabIndex="0" ... role="button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not getting an announcement because I had a key attribute that was changing. Once I made the key attribute a constant, the screen reader correctly announces "pressed" or "not pressed".

However, a better solution is to get of the button role and just have the title change based on whether or not it's pressed. When the title changes, it will announce the name title.